# Manage iOS and Android app localization/translation

Tags: android, ios, iphone-app, translation, localization

I am starting on a project to internationalize and localize a mobile app. The app comes in an iOS and Android version. They are two native apps, so they do not share any code, but obviously they contain the same text strings.

I am looking for a tool to manage the translations so the translation needs to be done only once. For example: if a translator translates the Android `strings.xml` file, the tool should automatically generate/update the iOS `.strings` file.

Other nice-to-have features:

- have a way to visualize where the translations are used (upload screenshots for example)
- integration with Git or BitBucket
- also manage translations of the App Store & Google Play Store

Of course I used google, but there are quite a few tools out there. I was wondering if somebody could point me out who are the big players, the tools I should definitely include in my comparison. Any pointers to some good articles, blog posts, which make a comparison would also be appreciated!

Comment: Which one did you end up choosing?

Comment: The client didn't continue with the project, so I never made the decision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some (re)search and came up with the following tools below (sorted by Alexa rating). I will pick five or so and do a little test project with them to see which one works best for my situation.

- https://transifex.com
- https://crowdin.com
- https://smartling.com
- https://oneskyapp.com
- https://poeditor.com
- https://phraseapp.com
- https://webtranslateit.com
- https://getlocalization.com
- https://lingohub.com
- https://lokalise.co
- https://weblate.org
- https://across.net
- https://alchemysoftware.com
- https://qordoba.com
- https://textunited.com
- https://applanga.com

Comment: weblate.org is open source. (The only one from the list?)

Comment: We use https://localise.biz which is not presented on your list. It has a free plan as well.